# Why standard SQL UDF increase the Bytes billed so much for all the query after it?

Tags: google-bigquery

BQ support team,

We recently investigate the Standard SQL with UDF in BQ, and seems it works pretty good. But we do noticed that it can be too costly to use it. As the Bytes billed can be hundred times than the original table. I think that makes sense as the UDF make need memory to process. But what I do not understand is that all the queries use the table generated by the UDF SQL still use the memory like the UDF SQL. Our original table is about 1.03K, and the UDF SQL run has a 10M billed. And below is the job info for a normal query:

> select * from `project.udf_sql_table_name`;

```
Job ID          *
Creation Time   Apr 14, 2017, 2:57:29 PM
Start Time      Apr 14, 2017, 2:57:29 PM
End Time        Apr 14, 2017, 2:57:30 PM
Bytes Processed 1.05 KB
Bytes Billed    10.0 MB
Billing Tier    1
Destination Table   *
Use Legacy SQL  fase
```

From the job info, we can see the UDF SQL generate a table about 1.05K, it is saved as project.udf_sql_table_name. And now even do a simple "SELECT", the "Bytes Billed" is still 10M, 1000 times bigger that the processed table. 
May I know is this correct when using UDF? 
Thanks

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the "Bytes Billed" is still 10M, 1000 times bigger that the processed table. ...  is this correct?

Yes. This is correct. See [`On-demand pricing`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing)

> Charges are rounded to the nearest MB, with a minimum 10 MB data
>   processed per table referenced by the query, and with a minimum 10 MB
>   data processed per query.